# Unreachable WMQ queue manager

Tags: networking

I'm a contractor using my client's machine to connect to my client's WMQ queue manager through my client's VPN For me, I get error code 2587, request timed out using my Java code, MQ Explorer and even Windows ping. Another consultant using the same setup got literally "host unreachable". Employees are able to reach successfully.

Is it reasonable to suspect we have a different VPN connection? I've never set one up for a large company, I don't know if they have like a contractor VPN and a separate regular VPN.

I'll tag WMQ for tge question, but suspect it's a network issue and not WMQ.